# Can I add another, different set of data to a row or column in the same sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to enter some analytics data from Twitter. I want to sort things by month. In each month, I want to have columns for 1st best tweet, 2nd best tweet, etc.

In each of these tweet columns, I want to have a way to organize data about them, like their text, their number of impressions etc. So essentially a way to organize the data for each of these individual tweets, within a particular month.

Is there a way to do this? I have included a picture below to illustrate. The italics are the other data I want to include for each of the specific tweet columns. Hopefully this makes sense.

I am thinking this question has been answered before but because I can't figure out how to word it I have not found an answer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Web Apps stackexchange, Rachel. Someone edited your question to remove anything conversational—they're pretty strict about that around here, and even these comments are not for chat. Two other things that could help your question are, first clarifying exactly what the question is. I know this is part of what you're trying to figure out but right now you've described the situation more than a problem you've hit. Second, a sheet filled with mock data, like in your picture, but Share it so Anyone With The Link can Edit, and add that back here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are already so close.

Having a list of the information you want to maintain, display, and use is half the battle. In looking at your example sheet, it seems the remaining task is formatting and organizing it? And perhaps deciding if you want the spreadsheet to summarize or calculate anything for you.

I'd strongly suggest some tweaks in the arrangement to something more common to spreadsheets. We're all accustomed to looking at websites—with their floating chunks of content and columns that have nothing to do with each other. One important norm for spreadsheets is that columns are for categories of information (like your labels) and *rows are for individual records*. In your spreadsheet, each month gets a row. But then we arrive at the tweet columns, and the data "turns" to go down, and rows become meaningless (for example the May tweets' Engagement are in the row for July!). Consider instead:

- Month-centric:  Each month gets its own row. Nothing from that row, in any column, is about another month. This will require many new columns: Tweet 1 Text, Tweet 1 Impressions, Tweet 1 Engagement, Tweet 2 Text…
- Tweet-centric:  Each tweet gets its own row. Everything about one tweet is in that one row, and nothing about that tweet is in any other row. This would require a new *column* for month, and several rows of successive tweets would just have the month repeated.
- Split:  At the bottom of each spreadsheet page are controls for "tabs"—different sheets of info in the same Google Sheets document. You could have a sheet with monthly summary data, and a different sheet for recording tweets and their stats.

Comment: Hi Joel, this was wonderfully helpful. I had seen your response the day of but I did not get a chance to reply until now. Thanks for spelling out to me how to arrange it, it makes sense. I see now that what I was trying to do will not work in a spreadsheet.

I will make a month-centric approach & add extra columns accordingly. I appreciate your response!